# SELENIUM PYTHON: How to pass automatic security validation?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium4

I am trying to get in this website: "https://core.cro.ie/".

I can get in using normal web search, but I can't get in using selenium.

My code looks like this:

```
site= "https://core.cro.ie/"

driver = webdriver.Edge(service=Service(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(site)
driver.maximize_window()
```

Any ideas? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for navigation ( I dont have Edge browser):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

site= "https://core.cro.ie/"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(site)
driver.maximize_window()
```

I have installed selenium prior running the test. It seems like the website has some sort of bot prevention mechanism but navigation works fine:

```
pip install selenium
```

Comment: Thank you @Alex Karamfilov. This code works in all the other websites. It only does not work in this one, because the website has a hidden captcha or something like that. My question, can I pass this?

Comment: Its not really hiddne captcha, they have implemented some sort of bot detection. There are some hints on how to workaround this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver

Comment: Add an intermediate step where while initializing the browser incorporate browser agents to mimic the actual user behaviour.  this should solve the issue